# Android - Asyntask doInBackground lag and stuck UI

Tags: android, for-loop, android-asynctask

I tried to do heavy process in background to avoid UI lag. When i do it in UI Thread, i got not responding, but when i do it in asyntask there is no not responding anymore, but the UI still lag and stuck for some time. This is my code.

```
private class GenerateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected final Void doInBackground(String... lists) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9000; j++) {
                final Keyword newKeyword = new Keyword();
                newKeyword.setId(j);
                newKeyword.setQuestion_answer_id(j);
                newKeyword.setKeyword("Keyword ke " + j + " " + UtilHelper.getLocation(j % 9));
                newKeyword.setUpdated_at(UtilHelper.getDateTime());
                //i think this is the one who causes the lag, but i still need this run on ui thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UtilDB db = new UtilDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        db.replaceKeyword(newKeyword);
                    }
                });
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to use background thread while updating in db. use handler thread for it

Comment: You're *assuming* it is running something against a Database... but if he felt the need to run it on UI Thread (indicating touching views etc.) then there's a chance the assumption is wrong

Comment: yeah, i actually i need to update some UI later, that's why i need that run on ui thread

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is abusing the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You can read the linked documentation so you can learn to use it (also why and when).

Remove:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        UtilDB db = new UtilDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        db.replaceKeyword(newKeyword);
    }
});
```

And replace with another method in AsyncTask:

```
public void onPostExecute(String newKeyword) {
    super.onPostExecute(newKeyword);
    UtilDB db = new UtilDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    db.replaceKeyword(newKeyword);
}
```

This requires changing to:

```
AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

Comment: you mention right use of asyntask but runOnUiThread and onPostExcecute both runs on UI thread. How it will avoid lag ?

Comment: but, if i do that, i only replace one row, what i want is update every row in my db, that's why i do replace in every loop.

Comment: actually the one who causes the lag is looping runs on UI thread, but i need to do that.

Comment: please post "replaceKeyword" code and then tag me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i would comment if i could (to less reputation) ... If i got you right you want to write in a Loop into a DataBase and **later** Update the UI?

> yeah, i actually i need to update some UI later, that's why i need that run on ui thread

Is it possible to split both? First write in DataBase in HandlerThread and then notify your UI to update via UiThread?

At the moment you are putting 9000 elements in the UiThread Queue, waiting to be processed. Thats a Lot of work ;)

Comment: ah, actually i need to update a view everytime i replace a row in my db. is it possible?

Comment: Hm then i dont know if it solves your lag problem but maybe u can perform db update in handler thread and than only update UI in UI Thread.

Or maybe update Ui only every 50, 100 or 500 Loops? (i guess there could be no visible delay for user but relaxes your ui thread)